# Merging data sets in R

Tags: r, merge

I am facing a trivial problem while merging 2 data.frames in R.

I am trying to merge 2 data.frames that have same column names and I would want R to merge the same name columns as one column instead of making it 2 separate columns.

Typically what happens when R encounters same name columns while merging data.frames is that it creates 2 seperate variables with suffix "x" and "y". Is there a way to specify this in the merge command to treat similar name columns in the different datasets as one column/variable?

The code that we could use as an example:

```
x = data.frame(id = c("a","c","d","g"), 
              maths = c(1,3,4,7),  physics = c(1,3,4,7),  chemistry = c(1,3,4,7),  
           english = c(1,3,4,7))
y = data.frame(id = c("b","c","d","e","f"),
                maths = c(5,6,8,9,7), physics = c(5,6,8,9,7), chemistry = c(5,6,8,9,7),
           english = c(5,6,8,9,7))

xy <- merge(x, y, by = "id")
```

Now there is a workaround for the same where we can create a new variable in the merged data set that takes the non N.A values from the same name columns, but this is very inefficient if you have large number of columns.

SAS users would relate to this problem as this problem was brought to my notice by a pro SAS user, where the merge() statement combines 2 same name columns into one column.

Also, as one of the answers below mentioned, if we use:

```
xy <- merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)))
```

We get no intersection between the 2 data.frames. Ideally we would want there to be 4 observations here, 2 for each observation in the 2 data.frames id = c("c","d")

Would be grateful to any pro R users to help me out on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add the desired output?

Comment: Do you want `merge(x,y,all=TRUE)`?

Comment: Yup Roland, the desired output would have one column for "maths", "physics" , "chemistry" and "english", instead of "maths.x" "maths.y".. and so on..

Comment: I understand that. My question is how you intend to combine columns if they have the same header but different values. Please add the desired result to your question.

Comment: Oh, I get that apologies for not being explicit. In the above example the way I would have it is if I have the "id" variable present in both the data.frames, there should be 2 separate observations created from them. But the above is just an illustrative example that I have create to address the broad questions of dealing with same column names in the 2 data.frames.

Comment: Well, then, as I said, just use the default for the `by` parameter (`by = intersect(names(x), names(y))`).

Comment: This is great thanks Roland. Just one small clarification, in this case we would not get any output if we remove the all = TRUE argument. Typically, I would expect the observations with id = ("c", "d") still be in the data set. So if you use merge(x, y, by = "id") you get the 2 observations, if you use merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y))), you get none. Any comments/thoughts?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33611/discussion-between-shreyes-and-roland)

Comment: Roland, have updated the question. Please let me know if there are still some ambiguities that need to be cleared. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to merge or is `rbind(x,y)`what you are looking for? In your example this results in the same `data.frame` (after sorting by `id`). If you want to actually merge the `data.frames`, you have to specify the names that you do not want to duplicate:

```
merge(x, y, all=TRUE)
merge(x, y, by = c("id", "maths", "physics", "chemistry", "english"), all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but would this potentially not lead to a case where this would merge observations where the variable "maths" or "physics" matches? Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Yup but the merge has to based on the values of only "id" and not "maths" or "physics". I was guessing the above code might merge the observations where the values of the variable "maths" matches across the 2 data.frames? Would it not?

Comment: This would merge observations where all of the `by` variables match! So if the id, maths, physics, chemistry and english are all the same, it would not duplicate it. Since in your example x and y have exactly the same names, this is the same as `rbind` and then removing duplicates.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification. I think I haven't been very explicit with the question. Let me just edit the question a bit with the desired output too. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

here is my quick solution.

Hope it helps. Note that the first column of x is my id to join

```
output <- merge(x[!(names(x)[2:length(names(x))] %in% names(y))], y, by.x = "id", by.y="id", all=TRUE)
```